# Why do we say "La operación... iniciado" instead of "ha/había iniciado"?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, pretérito

I'm reading news articles in Spanish to try and polish my skills, but I've hit a bump.  Below is a paragraph from an article:

> La operación es parte de un esfuerzo más amplio llamado Escudo Comunitario en el que participan fuerzas policiales anti-pandillas locales, estatales, federales e internacionales, iniciado en 2005, que busca identificar, arrestar, enjuiciar, encarcelar y deportar a los pandilleros y sus asociados con el fin de proteger a las comunidades.

An example of where I'm confused is "*ïniciado en 2005*".  Shouldn't this be written as "*ha/había iniciado en 2005*" to indicate either present perfect or pluperfect tense?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, *iniciado* works as an adjective, not too different from what you could write in English. Maybe your problem here is that the adjective is so far away from its noun (*esfuerzo*). Let's remove a bit of the sentence:

> La operación es parte de un esfuerzo [...] iniciado en 2005 [...]

It is easier to follow now, isn't it?

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to answer (+1). I just wanted to add that the article could have used a verb, changing the adjetive for a relative clause: _La operación es parte de un esfuerzo **que** se inició/había iniciado..._

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot the past participle could be an adjective.